# Using KMC-CMK on S3 with laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket that is used to store files via Laravel. I have updated the bucket policy to use a Customer-Managed CMK and I cannot figure out or find what configuration to use in Laravel

This is what I have in `config/filesystems` and it works fine with a standard bucket policy and AWS-Managed CMK

```
    's3' => [
        'driver'   => 's3',
        'key'      => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret'   => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region'   => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket'   => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url'      => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        'options'  => [
            'ServerSideEncryption' => env('AWS_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION'),

        ],
    ],
```

What changes do I have to make to be able to use a Customer-Managed CMK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly you are passing as `ServerSideEncryption` as you are getting it from an env var, but this are the options available in the [PHP SDK for PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject):

```
    'SSEKMSKeyId' => '<string>',
    'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256|aws:kms',
```

Based on that I believe that your configuration should look like this:

```
    's3' => [
        'driver'   => 's3',
        'key'      => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret'   => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region'   => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket'   => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url'      => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        'options'  => [
            'ServerSideEncryption' => 'aws:kms',
            'SSEKMSKeyId' => env('SSE_KMS_KEY_ARN')
        ],
    ],
```

where `SSE_KMS_KEY_ARN` is the ARN of the KMS CMK key with which you want to encrypt.

Comment: server Side Encryption with AWS KMS m (truncated...) InvalidArgument (client): Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed key requires HTTP header x-amz-server-side-encryption - i am getting this error